# Removing new line between xml tags in unix shell script

Tags: xml, bash, shell, unix, formatting

```
<mstr>
  <srt>Payment towards File# 1234</srt>
  <msg>info for treat sxc
  Pay to shankar  A/C#999999
  bank of ooty</msg>
  <ins>info for party BB
   Pay to kumar A/C#999999
   state bank</ins>
</mstr>
```

the above XML I would like to convert like below, meaning the data wrapped in the next line between the start and end tags. should in a single line like below.

```
 <mstr>
  <srt>Payment towards File# 1234</srt>
  <msg>info for treat sxc Pay to shankar  A/C#999999 bank of chen</msg>
  <ins>info for party BB Pay to kumar A/C#999999 state bank</ins>
</mstr>
```

I have tried the below way, by referring web answer. want to understand what below awk command does also looking for any other alternative to fix my issue?

```
 awk '{printf /^</&&!/^<\//?RS $0:$0}'
```

Comment: Does the answer you found work for you ? If not, could you show the output it gives ?

Comment: Don't use line oriented tools for parsing XML.

Comment: yes its worked, i want to understand how the awk applied here

Comment: Some call it [summoning the daemon](https://www.metafilter.com/86689/), others refer to it as [the Call for Cthulhu](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) and few just [turned mad and met the Pony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8344060). In short, never parse XML or HTML with a regex! Did you try an XML parser such as `xmlstarlet`, `xmllint` or `xsltproc`?

Comment: xmllint  i used this , but doesnt helped

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest, although there are for sure better alternatives, is to use awk on a [PYX format](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-matters17/x-matters17-pdf.pdf) file. The PYX format is a line-oriented representation of XML documents that is derived from the SGML ESIS format. (see ESIS - ISO 8879 Element Structure Information Set spec, ISO/IEC JTC1/SC18/WG8 N931 (ESIS)).

The PYX format is extremely simple to describe and understand. The first character on each line identifies the content-type of the line. Content does not directly span lines, although successive lines might contain the same content-type. In the case of tag attributes, the attribute name and value are simply separated by a space, without the use of extra quotes. The prefix characters are:

```
( start-tag
) end-tag
A attribute
- character data (content)
? processing instruction
```

So we can ask , xmlstarlet to convert the XML into PYX, use awk to remove the lines, and convert it back to an XML file:

```
$ xmlstarlet pyx file.xml | sed -E '/^-\\n/b;/^-/s/\\n +/ /g' | xmlstarlet p2x -
```

Comment: Love this. I might suggest `sed -E 's/\\n[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]])/ \1/g'` in the middle, but it's not that great of an improvement.

Comment: +1 for bringing ESIS into the discussion; something I didn't dare because it's so old (Perl times), even though it's the most general technique to bring SGML/XMLish input to line-oriented Unix tools. Btw you can also use the `onsgmls`/`nsgmls` program from the OpenSP SGML processing package to produce ESIS from any SGML or XML

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation to the `awk` script.

```
awk '{printf /^</&&!/^<\//?RS $0:$0}'
```

Hope screen image is clear.

[image]

Comment: This is not code insertion this is code documentation.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data. The above image can be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML aware tool to handle XML, using `sed` or `awk` might break the data easily.

For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a tool I happen to maintain, which is in fact a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML), you can do:

```
open file.xml ;
for /mstr/* set . normalize-space(.) ;
save :b ;
```

The output is almost the expected one - it just keeps "ooty" instead of "chen", but that can be easily fixed by adding

```
set /mstr/msg xsh:subst(/mstr/msg, 'ooty', 'chen') ;
```

Comment: looks intriguing. I notice the "XSH2 manual page" link is broken.

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks, I'll fix it. [Ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=129801)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do - removing space characters at the begin and end of text, and collapse any sequence of space and newline characters into just as single space character within text - is known as *whitespace normalization* in XML, and can be done by many XML processing tools out of the box without need for ad-hoc shell scripting. For example, you can use `tidy` (available at http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ and might be already installed on your machine or installable via `sudo apt-get install tidy` on Debian/Ubuntu) as follows to whitespace-normalize your input (assumed to be stored in `test.xml`):

```
tidy -xml -w 80 test.xml
```

Your awk one-liner prints any input line (`$0`), omits newlines (by using `printf()` rather than `print()`), and prepends `RS` (record separator, the tab character by default) before an output line if the line begins with what looks like a start-element tag (`/</`), yet doesn't look like an end-element tag (`!/^<\//`). The two regexp tests are combined with the `&&` logical and operator, and are part of a conditional expression with everything before the `?` character the test condition, and the part following `?` representing the "if" and "else" branch, respectively, to take depending on the conditional, separated by `:`. For your input, the awk program will output everything on a single line (without terminating newline character), and prepending a tab character before each start-element tag. It would fail to separate consecutive text lines by a space character, and incorrectly passes the whole input line as the first argument to `printf()` such that a percent character in your input text, interpreted as a placholder in `printf` format strings, would break your output.

Do yourself a favour and use real XML or SGML tools for processing markup.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a scripting language with an XML parsing module. For example, with ruby:

```
ruby -r'rexml/document' -e '
    file = ARGV.shift
    doc = REXML::Document.new(File.new(file))
    doc.elements.each("/mstr/*") {|child| child.text = child.text.gsub(/\n\s*/, " ")}
    File.open(file, "w") {|f| f.puts(doc.to_s)}
' file.xml
```

results in the file

```
<mstr>
  <srt>Payment towards File# 1234</srt>
  <msg>info for treat sxc Pay to shankar  A/C#999999 bank of ooty</msg>
  <ins>info for party BB Pay to kumar A/C#999999 state bank</ins>
</mstr>
```